# Create a delay between rendering captured frames on Eevee

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine

It may seem strange, but I need to know how to create a delay between my frames when rendering animation in Eevee (for example, I have an animation that contains 50 frames, I want the first frame that was rendered to render the next frame or frames  next is 3 seconds delay), can someone help me?

Comment: tbh i have no idea what you exactly want. So you want to render e.g. 50x the same image because you need it for 3 seconds? if this is the case: you would never render the same image over and over again. You would use the VSE and just import that one image and then make the strip longer which is much faster. If this isn't the case, please explain in more detail how your end result should look like. And no comment or answer after 9 hours means: other people have problems understanding your question as well but don't want to ask....

Comment: I want to create a delay of a few seconds after each frame is rendered, then it will go to render the next frame

Comment: A  hold (freeze) on each frame for 3 seconds? Perhaps clarify that in an edit, if so.

Comment: so you really want that Blender stops working for 3 seconds and then renders the next frame? is that what you want? if yes, why do you wanna do that? so that your computer doesn't burn and can cool down? (just kidding)

Comment: Is it possible to do something like this?